# Facebook login button with oauth 2 not calling auth.login

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, oauth-2.0

Our Asp.net site has been using the facebook login button (w/ javascript sdk) to handle the login process, and now that Oauth is mandatory (as of Dec 15, 2011 (yesterday))- it is broken.  I've made some obvious changes that were mentioned the [fb oauth migration blog](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/525/), but still I'm getting errors.  Specifically, when FB.init()'s parameter sets status=false, the auth.login event is never fired (which is a problem, because I use callback on that event to invoke another page which does some server-side open graph queries based on the authorization token in the resulting cookie).  If I set status=true, then the event is fired, but the cookie is not set, and so I'm unable to make my server-side open graph queries.

Here's my javascript code (slightly edited...):

```
  window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
        FB.init({
            appId: GetFacebookAppId(),
            status: true, 
            cookie: true,
            xfbml: true,
            oauth: true
        });

        FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function (response) {
            if (response.authResponse && response.authResponse.accessToken)
                FacebookLoginRedirect(); 
        });
   }
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try `FB.getLoginStatus()` instead of `if (response.authResponse && response.authResponse.accessToken)`

See detaild example [here in the docs](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/) : ]

Comment: that works if fb.init { ..., status: true, ... }, but i want to set status=false to work w/ my existing code.  when status=false, then the auth.login event does not fire.  that's the big problem.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully someone finds this useful- I was able to listen to a different event: auth.statusChange, check the response, and then proceed.  One thing was that I had to unsubscribe to this event once I had successfully logged in, but then it seemed to work ok.

Answer (score 0):

listen to auth.statusChange :

```
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', handleStatusChange);
```